# How do I solve the error "Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') ?"

Tags: php, composer-php, phpdotenv

So I am using vlucas/phpdotenv in my php application to store and use environment variables. I have created a db.php file which contains the configuration of my database connection. The folder structure is root/config/db.php.

I have `require('../vendor/autoload.php');` in the db.php file and then I have used

```php
$dotenv=Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable('../');
$dotenv->load();
print_r($_ENV);
```

to access the environment variables since the .env file is in the root of the directory. It all works perfectly fine when i access the db.php file on the server but when I include this file in the register.php file which is in the root I get the error "Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR')".

However when I change the directory of the autoload.php to match the path I then get this error:
"Uncaught Dotenv\Exception\InvalidPathException: Unable to read any of the environment file(s) at [../.env]."

Can someone please help me out here? Thank you.

Comment: Hello have you created the .env file?

Comment: Yes I have created a .env file in the root folder which contains all the database information like username, password, host, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using a relative path, but expecting it to function like an absolute path.

the ../ notation meant the parent directory, so if you move the file the parent directory changes also.

Instead of working relatively, I prefer to set a base and work upwards.

Use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, which is the file path to the root of your application.

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/vendor/autoload.php');
```

Then use the same notation in you `createImmutable` static call. I don't know where you're supposed to be pointing that to. If it's the root, use...

```
$dotenv=Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
$dotenv->load();
print_r($_ENV);
```

Answer (score 0):

So let's look at this.
Your directory structure seems to be something like this:

```
/
|- register.php
|- login.php
|- .env
|- /config
   |- db.php
```

There are several problems with this. One of them is: Files that *should not* be accessible by web browsers are accessible. (try to call your-domain.com/.env If you didn't protect this by a .htaccess file, then you'll leak your database information to public)

But coming back to your problem:
`../` is a relative path. Relative to the file, that was the entry point for the call.
Let's look at it: If you call `config/db.php`, then the `current working directory` will be `config` and `../` will point to the root path.
If you call `register.php`, then the `current working directory` will be the root path and `../` will point to the parent directory.

You should go with something like this:

```
/
|- /public
   |- login.php
   |- register.php
|- .env
|- bootstrap.php
|- /conf
   |- db.php
```

Every file in `public` should include `bootstrap.php`, where dotenv will be executed. And instead of something like `'./env'`, you can use `__DIR__/ . '.env'`.
There are several benefits from this:

- You don't risk leaking sensible files/data
- You always have the same include path and don't have to worry, from where to call this file

Drawbacks:

- You have to configure your server to serve the public folder instead of the root directory.

Comment: Yess that is exactly how my folder structure is right now. Is there a way i can create an access block to the .env file incase someone types in www.website.com/.env without changing the folder structure ?

Also given your folder structure how would someone be blocked from accessing the .env file in the browser? Thanks for your help on this. :D

Also as @hubare mentioned i was able to fix it using the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] method.

Comment: > Is there a way i can create an access block to the .env file incase someone types in www.website.com/.env 
Yes. You can define in your `.htaccess`, what files must not be served. (Assuming, you use Apache.)
>  Also given your folder structure how would someone be blocked from accessing the .env file in the browser? 
You would set the server's web root to `/public`. So there can't be any files outside of `/public` accessed. 
(If you look at any modern framework, they all have a `/public` folder)

Comment: >(Assuming, you use Apache.)  I am actually not using Apache. I am running it on the PHP server using 'php -S localhost':XXXX.>

>You would set the server's web root to /public. So there can't be any files outside of /public accessed. Oh yes that makes sense. Thanks a lot > I have noticed a lot of modern frameworks using public as their root directory. Thanks a lot for your help.